# modifying nth line after matching pattern

Tags: regex, shell, sed, awk

I need to modify a file containing huge number of ldifs. Basically the structure of file is like this. I call this file as file-1.

```
 cn: username1
 gidNumber: 222
 loginShell: /bin/bash
 objectClass: inetOrgPerson
 objectClass: shadowAccount
 uid: username1
 mail:

 cn: username2
 ...
```

So I need match cn: example1 and then change corresponding mail: i.e 6th line after matching. I have another file called file-2 from where I'm going to take new value to modify. The file-2 having syntax like this.

```
 username1 abc@email.com
 username2 bcd@email.com
 ...
```

So I want to do like this. Take username1 from file-2 match it in file-1 if match found then modify the 6th line from match (i.e mail: in above case) to corresponding value abc@email.com taken from file-2. Doing this for all values in file-2.

How to achieve this using sed or awk ? I have done this primary unsuccessful try.

```
 input=file-2
 a="sn: "
 b="mail: "
 while read -r line
 do
    read -r f1 f2  <<<"$line"
    c=$b$f2
    d=$a$f1
    sed -i 's/\($d\)\(.*\)/\1$c/' file-1
 done<"$input"
```

Comment: You can only use sed and awk? Otherwise you could always give it a try to Perl

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this by counting the number of lines after `cn:`. If someone changes the format of file-1 so that there are more lines, or the lines are in a different order, your code will fail and have to be modified. Or, worse, the number of lines may not even be known at compile time, if some lines are optional or if the parts after `:` are allowed to contain newlines. Instead, you should write code that finds the first `mail:` line after your `cn:` line.

Comment: @delephin Actually I don't know much about perl. I know some basic of sed and awk.

Comment: @DavidKnipe Ya,you are right, my approach was not appropriate. Thanks for the information ..!! Got the correct answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work (as script.awk):

```
NR==FNR {
    m[$1]=$2
    next
}

$1=="cn:" { u=$2 }

$1=="mail:" {
    print "mail: " m[u]
    next
}

1
```

Run as `awk -f script.awk file-2 file-1`.

The `NR==FNR` bit loops over all the lines in the first file (because the total seen record number `NR` is the same as the current file's record number `NR`). While doing that it builds up an associative array/hash mapping usernames to email addresses.

The rest of the script then captures the most recently seen username (the `$1=="cn:" bit) and stores that in a variable. When the script next sees a line that starts with`mail:`(the`$1=="mail:" bit) it prints out `mail: <the saved email for the currently stored username>` and moves on.

The `1` at the end is just awk shorthand for print the current line (the action for a pattern defaults to `{print}` and any pattern that evaluates to true will run its action). Any non-zero non-empty string value would work in place of `1` there as well.

Comment: Thanks..!! It worked for me. Can you give me some explanation how this script works if possible ? I'm learning sed & awk, just want to know how this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Given your username -> email mappings in a file called `emails.txt`, and this `script.awk`:

```
NR == FNR { emails[$1] = $2; next }
$1 == "cn:" { username = $2; }
$1 == "mail:" { print $1, emails[username]; next }
1
```

You could run this for your mappings file and ldif file with:

```
awk -f script.awk emails.txt file.ldif
```